# Transition on Expandable ListView collapse and expand

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to achieve transition when the expandable listview is expanded and collapsed. If anyone any layout modification or any third party API please let me know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for an [AnimatedExpandableListView](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView).